# How to access Azure Function JSON response properties in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I created a Azure Function in C# that returns more than one parameters in a JSON response:

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {
    empId= "e101", name = "John"
});
```

I'm able to access this function in Azure logic apps, but I have no idea how to access the individual properties returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change to the **Logic App Code View** and modify your binding expressions to do this.

For example, I created an Azure Function just like yours, and added an Http Response action that consumes one of the JSON properties from my function response. In the Logic App Designer, I bound to the entire `Body` returned by my function. Then in the Code View I modified the binding expression to access the specific body property `empId` (where `<function-app-name>` will be your app name):

```
"Response": {
    "inputs": {
        "body": "@body('<function-app-name>')['empId']",
        "statusCode": 200
    },
```

You should be able to modify your Action in the same way to access the JSON properties. You'll also notice that after switching back to the Designer, the bound properties will display correctly.

We'll improve this experience over time so you don't have to drop down to code like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. although i did like  {body('azure_fun_Name').empId}

Answer (score 1):

There is now a new action call "Parse JSON" that will let you define the schema and parse the response so you get a nice design experience to grab properties.  Let me know if you have any questions on it.